# Java чтение файла из консоли

Tags: java

Как прочитать имя файла из консоли на java, при том, что вводим как "c:/path/file.ext" или "file.ext"
Как распознать какой путь ввели и открыть этот файл?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String file = reader.readLine();
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = null;

while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
//непонятно
}
```

Comment: В общем то ваш код и отвечает на ваш первый вопрос.  Распознать путь можно попробовать регулярками, но зачем оно вам?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886201/java-outputting-text-file-to-console

Answer (score 1):

Для распознавания пути можно использовать метод `isAbsolute()` у экземпляра класса `File`:

```
File file1 = new File("file.ext");
File file2 = new File("C:\\path\\to\\file.ext");
System.out.println(file1.isAbsolute());    // false
System.out.println(file2.isAbsolute());    // true
```

Преобразовать путь из относительного в абсолютный можно следующими методами:

- `getAbsoluteFile()` - возвращает новый экземпляр типа `File` с абсолютным путём
- `getAbsolutePath()` - возвращает строку с абсолютным путём

Получить относительный путь из абсолютного чуть сложнее:

```
String workingDir = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString();
String relative = new File(workingDir).toURI().relativize(file2.toURI()).getPath();
System.out.println(relative);
```

Для этого получаем текущую рабочую директорию и смотрим путь относительно неё.